# Why my HDD is in use at 100% by SYSTEM when I'm logged off, but the moment I login, I get 0% Disk usage?

Tags: windows

[image]

I'm on win 10 pro, and this is not the first time I see it happening. I only noticed because is noisy. Anyone knows why? it keeps doing this for days.

The arrow indicates the moment I login the user account.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is designed to run several programs/services when it is idle, even before you login to your account. This includes Task Scheduler and Defrag.exe, but could also be incomplete Windows update, or corrupted files (system files) or startup applications, etc. First check the Defrag program because it is the first suspect. Right-click on your hard disk icon and click on Properties, then Tools, then Optimize. Check if it is enabled on your HDD or not, and you can disable it from there.

Comment: Found it... was defragment. So hard to find it